# About a claim in limits

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Let $a_n\geq 0$.

If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=L$ then
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sqrt[k]{a_n}=\sqrt[k]{L}$, $(k\in N)$

I am trying to show this using that:
$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+...+b^{k-1})$.

Comment: *Hint* Use the fact that $(a_n)$ is bouded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $L=0$ the result is true (you can check directly by defining limit). If $L \neq 0$, how $a_n \geq 0$ then $L > 0$. Then  using that $a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+...+b^{k-1})$ with $a=\sqrt[k]{a_n}$ and $b=\sqrt[k]{L}$, we obtain
$$ \sqrt[k]{a_n}-\sqrt[k]{L} = \dfrac{a_n-L}{ (\sqrt[k]{a_n})^{k-1}+(\sqrt[k]{a_n})^{k-2}L+...+L^{k-1} }.$$
Then
$$|\sqrt[k]{a_n}-\sqrt[k]{L}| = \dfrac{|a_n-L|}{ |(\sqrt[k]{a_n})^{k-1}+(\sqrt[k]{a_n})^{k-2}L+...+L^{k-1} |} \leq \dfrac{|a_n-L|}{ |L|^{k-1}}$$

How $a_n$ is convergent, given $\varepsilon$ choose $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq n_0$ implies $|a_n-L| < |L|^{k-1}\varepsilon$. So from the above equation results

$$|\sqrt[k]{a_n}-\sqrt[k]{L}|  \leq \dfrac{|L|^{k-1}\varepsilon}{ |L|^{k-1}} = \varepsilon.$$